# Convert barcode scan string to variables

Tags: php, arrays, numbers, substr, datamatrix

I have a barcode that after being scanned it needs to be split into five variables.

```
Example barcode scan: 0109556135082301172207211060221967 21Sk4YGvF8
Alternate scan: 010955704600017017250630102107015
```

There are 5 delimiters

```
01 - gtin (14 DIGIT only)
11 - production date (YYMMDD)
17 -  expire date (YYMMDD)
10 - batch no (can be variable but not more than 20 digit)  
<space>21 - serial no (can be variable but not more than 20 digit)


01
09556135082301 (gtin)
17
220721 (production date)
10
60221967 (batch number)
 21
Sk4YGvF8 (serial number)
```

This is my attempt:

```
$str = "0109556135082301172207211060221967 21Sk4YGvF8"

if ($strtemp != null){
    $ais = explode("_",$str);
    for ($aa=0;$aa<sizeof($ais);$aa++)
    {
        $ary = $ais[$aa];
        while(strlen($ary) > 0) {
            if (substr($ary,0,2)=="01"){
                $igtin = substr($ary,2,14);
                $ary = substr($ary,-(strlen($ary)-16));
            }

            else if (substr($ary,0,2)=="17"){
                $expirydate = substr($ary,6,2)."-".substr($ary,4,2)."-20".substr($ary,2,2);
                $ary = substr($ary,-(strlen($ary)-8));
            }
            else if (substr($ary,0,2)=="10"){
                $batchno = substr($ary,2,strlen($ary)-2);
                $ary = "";
            }
            else if (substr($ary,0,2)=="21"){
                $serialno = substr($ary,2,strlen($ary)-2);
                $ary = "";
            }
            else if (substr($ary,0,2)=="11"){
                $proddate = substr($ary,6,2)."-".substr($ary,4,2)."-20".substr($ary,2,2);
                $ary = substr($ary,-(strlen($ary)-8));
            }

            else {
                $oth = "";
            }
        }
```

The result desired:

| Items | Result |
| --- | --- |
| GTIN | 09556135082301 |
| EXPIRE DATE | 21-07-2022 |
| BATCH/LOT NUMBER | 60221967 |
| SERIAL NUMBER | Sk4YGvF8 |

From my code above the variable come out like this:

| Items | Result |
| --- | --- |
| GTIN | 09556135082301 |
| EXPIRE DATE | 21-07-2022 |
| BATCH/LOT NUMBER | 6022196721Sk4YGvF8 |
| SERIAL NUMBER |  |

Comment: Your code is too long to read. Would you mind some other approach?

Comment: I already edit the code

Comment: You need to define where $strtemp comes from.   `str =` is not valid.   I see not data that has an under line ("_" ) character.  What is being exploded?

Comment: @nice_dev  I reedit the question, can you help me to have a look?

Comment: @devilgg86 Sure, but can you also add how the barcode would look if it had production date?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE**
I have it and it is tested.

```
$str = "0109556135082301172207211060221967 21Sk4YGvF8";
$len = strlen($str);
$gtin = substr($str,2,14);
$date = '20' . substr($str,18,6);
$production = substr($date,0,4) . '-' .  substr($date,4,2) . '-' .  substr($date,6,2);
$time = strtotime($production);
$production = date('M d, Y',$time);
$position =  strrpos($str,' 21');
$serial = substr($str,$position + 2);
$start = strrpos($str,'10',23) + 2;
$batch = substr($str, $start,$position - $start);

echo"\nlen: ";
print_r($len);
echo"\ngtin: ";
print_r($gtin);
echo"\nproduction: ";
print_r($production);
echo"\nposition: ";
print_r($position);
echo"\nbatch: ";
print_r($batch);
echo"\nserial: ";
print_r($serial);



 $str = "010955704600017017250630102107015";

 $len = strlen($str);
 $gtin = substr($str,2,14);
 $position = strpos($str,'17',14) + 2;
 $date = '20' . substr($str,$position,6);
 $expires = substr($date,0,4) . '-' .  substr($date,4,2) . '-' .  substr($date,6,2);
$time = strtotime($expires);
$expires = date('M d, Y',$time);
$start = strpos($str,'10',22) + 2;
$batch = substr($str, $start);


echo"\n\n\nlen: ";
print_r($len);
echo"\ngtin: ";
print_r($gtin);
echo"\nexpires: ";
print_r($expires);
echo"\nposition: ";
print_r($position);
echo"\nbatch: ";
print_r($batch);
```

Results

```
len: 45
gtin: 09556135082301
production: Jul 21, 2022
position: 34
batch: 60221967
serial: 1Sk4YGvF8


len: 33
gtin: 09557046000170
expires: Jun 30, 2025
position: 18
batch: 2107015
```

I doubt there is a bullet proof algorithm to extract all the variables every time with your current syntax.  The barcode is just not structured correctly for it to be done reliably.

**If you can change the barcode format, I do it this way:**

```
$str = "0955613508230|220721|60221967|Sk4YGvF8";
list($gtin,$date,$batch,$serial) = explode('|',$str);
echo "gtin: $gtin\nDate: $date\nBatch: $batch\nSerial: $serial";
```

[**Online Demo**](https://onecompiler.com/php/3yg8q975p)

**END OF UPDATE**

I think I may have it.

```
01
09556135082301
17
220721
10
60221967
21
Sk4YGvF8
```

Getting the gtin and expires is simple due to the fixed value lengths.  
Presuming "21" will not show up in the serial number. strrpos finds the last position of "21" in $str.  So serial number is from that position + 2 where +2 is for the length of "21" and take the substring from that position to the end.
The use the end position of the expires to the position of "21" to get the $batch.

```
$len = strlen($str);
$gtin = substr($str,2,14);
$expires = substr(18,6);
$position = strrpos('21', $str) + 2;
$serial = substr($str,$position);
$batch = substr($str,24,$len - $position);
```

Comment: thank for the answer given.  just the got error on the position. I change to $position = strrpos($str,'21') +2;  but I check it most fixed length, if the expires data want to convert to 21-07-22 then how should it be?

Comment: thank for the answer given.  just the got error on the position. I change to $position = strrpos($str,'21') +2;  but I check it most fixed length, if change another barcode it show incorrect data you may check https://onecompiler.com/php/3yg79t5xt . it show be have gtin, expire data & batch no only.

Comment: I provide the wrong datamatrix barcode input it should be have spacebar before the 21 then continue with the barcode. It is able to do the logic?

Comment: @devilgg86 I posted the new code using `$str =  "0109556135082301172207211060221967 21Sk4YGvF8";`  What's the deal with `$str = "010955704600017017250630102107015";`? The fix was quick and easy

Answer (score 0):

```
else if (substr($ary,0,2)=="10"){
    $batchno = substr($ary,2,strlen($ary)-2);
    $ary = "";
}
```

To answer your question. The reason is when "10" is found, the remaining string is used. you need do what you've done in other branches.

---

Give you some advice. Your approach is hard to read, you'd better use `for` and `switch` to optimze the code like this:

```
for($i = 0; $i < strlen($ary); )
{
    $h = substr($ary, $i, 2);
    $i += 2;
    switch($h)
    {
        case '01':
           $igtin = substr($ary,$i,14);
           $i += 14;
           break;

        case '10':
        .......
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks , if the str didnt have the bracket  and str llike this  $str = '010955613508230117220721106022196721Sk4YGvF8';  then how the approach are? as 10 is batch number and following the serial number but batch number is variable length so how should I code it?

Comment: Ur... but I don't change your main logic, I assume the string doesn't have the bracket

Comment: @shingo  possible to change the str into readable information?